# Showing a message in console in backbonejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, router

I am trying to show a message in console using backbone js. Here is what I have tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Backbone</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1> User Manager</h1>
    </div>


    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.is.js/0.2.1/jquery.is.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.0/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

            routes: {
                '' : 'home'
            }
        });
        var router = new Router();
        router.on('route:home', function () {

            console.log('rout is loaded');
        });

        Backbone.history.start();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

After trying this I am getting this error below:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined  on jquery.is.min.js:10
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object # is not a function   on backbone.js 1388
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined    on measureIt.js:120**

Whats wrong with my router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link which you are using is not a valid jquery link. Try changing it.

```
    //invalid link
    http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.is.js/0.2.1/jquery.is.min.js
```

Correct link

```
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: Actually `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.is.js/0.2.1/jquery.is.min.js` is a valid link. It's a script to `Check your data against regular expressions or known keywords`

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you're currently missing the core jQuery file. Try to include it.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.is.js/0.2.1/jquery.is.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.0/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

or if you want the CDN file from `cloudflare` then use:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.is.js/0.2.1/jquery.is.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.0/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: use this url instead: `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js` You don't really want to connect to multiple servers.

Comment: Ok, added your suggestion.

Comment: thanks it works , But I am getting another error message in my console  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined measureIt.js:120  , what is this ? I didn't add measureIt.js .

Comment: Try to change `'' : 'home'` to `'*path': 'home'`. Actually. your code works fine for me! I don't know why as well :P